# Measurable functions with the same integral over a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R,g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ are Lebesgue measurable with $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)=1$.

How to show that for every $r\in(0,1)$, there is a measurable $E \subset \mathbb R$ such that $\int_{ E}f(x)=\int_{ E}g(x)=r$?

Comment: What have you got so far?  Also, I gave the question a more descriptive title; feel free to edit if you don't like it.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to construct a $F_\sigma$ set, but failed.

Comment: I don't understand why this should be true. If $f$ and $g$ correspond to two probability densities, say Gaussian and Cauchy respectively, why should the corresponding probability measures put same mass on a set.

Comment: @Leitingok, why you post the question in that form? If $\int_\mathbb{R} f=\int_\mathbb{R} g$, then $f=g$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$, and then almost everywhere in any subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If that is true, why this question considers two functions? Can someone explain please?

Comment: @leo, $\int_\mathbb{R} f=\int_\mathbb{R}g$ means roughly that the net signed area between the $x$-axis and the graphs of $f$ and $g$ are equal.  This does not imply that $f=g$ almost everywhere.  E.g., consider Ashok's examples of probability density functions.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: This post remembers me a result that says: $\int_E f =0$ if and only if $f=0$ a.e. Perhaps, this result requiere aditional hypothesis on $E$ and/or $f$. That's the reason of my comment

Comment: @leo: This holds if $f \ge 0$ a.e.  It is obviously false otherwise: take for example $f(x) = \sin x$ with $E = [-\pi,\pi]$.  There are also various results saying that if $\int_E f = 0$ *for every $E$ in a certain collection of sets*, then $f = 0$ a.e.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thanks for the enlightenment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $r = 1/2$, there is an *interval* $E$ for which this holds.  Several proofs of this fact are given in:

> Totik, Vilmos.  A tale of two integrals.  *American Mathematical Monthly* **106**: 227-240, 1999.  [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1682343) | [Full text (JSTOR)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589678)

(These proofs are given replacing the domain $\mathbb{R}$ with $[0,1]$, so apply the obvious transformation.  Totik also gives a proof that the desired equality holds with $E$ an interval *if and only if* $r = 1/k$ for some integer $k$.)

So let $E_1$ be an (open) interval such that $\int_{E_1} f = \int_{E_1} g = 1/2$.  Then by applying the same result to $f_1 = 2f1_{E_1^c}$, $g_1 = 2 g 1_{E_1^c}$, we can produce $E_2$, disjoint from $E_1$, with $\int_{E_2} f = \int_{E_2} g = 1/4$.  ($E_2$ may not be an interval, because we have to remove $E_1$ from it, but we can take it to be a finite union of open intervals.)  Proceeding, we can produce disjoint sets $E_n$ with $\int_{E_n} f = \int_{E_n} g = 2^{-n}$.  Now consider the binary expansion of $r$ and take the union of the corresponding $E_n$.  The resulting set $E$ is not only measurable but in fact *open*.

Hopefully I didn't overlook any subtle details...

Comment: I don't have the paper. what happens when r=1/2?

Comment: @Leitingok, Nate provides links to the [Full text](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2589678) paper. Perhaps is better to access at your university.

Answer (score 4):

In the special case $f\ge 0$, $g\ge 0$, this follows from a theorem of Lyapunov stating that the range of a vector measure is convex.  In the present context this means that the set $R:=\{(\int_E f(x)\,dx,\int_E g(x)\,dx): E\in{\mathcal L}\}$ is a convex subset of $[0,1]^2$. (Here ${\mathcal L}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of the real line.) Since $R$ clearly contains $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, it contains the segment connecting them. Therefore  for each $r\in(0,1)$ the point $(r,r)$ is an element of $R$, and so there exists $E\in{\mathcal L}$ with $\int_E f=\int_E g = r$.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have a reference for this theorem?

Comment: Lyapunov's paper "Sur les fonctions-vecteurs complétement additives" is here: [Izvestia Akad. Nauk SSSR, vol. 4 (1940) pp. 465-478].  There is a nice exposition in an article by D. Ross in the American Mathematical Monthly [vol. 112 (2005) pp. 651-653].